# Save screen position when changing to different activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have a relativelayout with 30 buttons within a scrollview.  What I would like to know is if there is a way of saving the position, ie. when the user has scrolled down to the second last button and clicked on it to display an image or text, and when pressed back to select a different button to return to the last position (which was the second last button for example) without having to scroll all the way down again? I had a sliding drawer and it worked fine, but with the buttons (which are image buttons) it takes a while to load the screen with all the buttons.  And I found doing it without the sliding drawer it loads faster but now have to scroll all the way down to the button every time I return to the buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android docs [say here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html):

> [...] you should use the onPause() method to write any
>   persistent data (such as user edits) to storage. In addition, the
>   method onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) is called before placing the
>   activity in such a background state, allowing you to save away any
>   dynamic instance state in your activity into the given Bundle, to be
>   later received in onCreate(Bundle) if the activity needs to be
>   re-created.

Perhaps you just recreating your activity content by accident.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Have got it sorted when looking at the Android Development website. Sorry got myself completely confused with this.  Thank you again.